# Having a professional website

Tags: career-development, websites

I currently have a website that I created that I was planning to use to display my portfolio. The only issue is that it isn't the fanciest website out there. I was wondering would this hurt my chances of getting a job?

I am not a front-end web developer, but I will be looking for a java developer position soon.

I was considering getting it re-done by a professional web developer, but I feel like this might mislead certain future employers.

Comment: Unless you are hunting for a job as a web developer, basic is fine. If you do want to showcase skills in this area you have the option of making this site part of your portfolio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A portfolio website can say a lot about you as a programmer/developer and that's largely why I would advise against hiring it out. If it ends up looking great and an interviewer, particularly a web savy interviewer, likes it and asks how you did X, it may look bad if you don't know.

Also, not to put too fine a point on it, there may be an inclination for an interviewer to think "what sort of programmer can't handle simple HTML and a little css?"

Your site doesn't necessarily need to be "fancy". Simple, clean, and maintainable should probably be the goal. Keep in mind that it's a resume/portfolio not your usual internet click bait.

Answer (score 2):

Craigslist.org is still one of the most effective websites even though it was founded in 1996 and has very little "styling" compared to modern websites.

Why is it so effective?

It conveys the exact information the user is looking for in as simple a manner as possible.

If you are seeking a position as a Java developer, a plain website is perfectly fine.

Black text on a white background, with a basic font and centered for readability is probably all you need.

Think of your website and an extended resume, where you can post longer-form text and code samples demonstrating your projects and abilities.

Put yourself in the hiring manager's shoes, what is the most important information you'd be looking for in a candidate? Put that information front and center of your website!

Answer (score 1):

The website potentially represents you in every way, and it will be seen as part of the application.
If it's professional, it will be to your advantage. If it looks like too expensive though, you may be seen as someone wasting resources, which wouldn't be good.
If it looks great, even if you didn't make it, it shows that probably you'll have an eye on websites that you work on (even if you don't do every bit in person). If it looks sloppy, you might be seen as sloppy.
If it looks super simple but also neat (like academic websites from the 90s), you might be seen as the perfect nerd (which might help if you are one) and as a practical person. And so on.

Bottom line: Each thing you do can be interpreted in a lot of ways, often both positive and negative ones. There's no general rule.
That's why I'd make it consistent with what you're going to represent in the application process. If you're a Java developer, it's okay if it's not super great with respect to its design or mobile-friendliness, but it should indicate that you work carefully (no typos, clean code, general design principles followed that you'd also adhere to in a Word document etc.).
Suggesting skills that you don't really have is unnecessary and can become counterproductive, but even this isn't always so. The greatest website might win the application process, and yet they never ask the winner to do the same for them. It's somehow a matter of luck.
If you ask me, I recommend to stay consistent and practical. My foremost suggestion is that you should like the website and not be shy to present it and that it should be consistent with the job you're applying for.